# Create Dynamic ItemTemplate based on GUID column names

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a process that pivots data to create columns based on the UniqueIdentifier key value.  The resulting data table has column names such as:

```
> PartNum
> [DB1A6498-7CC6-4EA0-846A-9B6EAB771777]
```

The portion of ASP is:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Part No.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPartNum" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PartNum") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Run Out">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRunOut" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DB1A6498-7CC6-4EA0-846A-9B6EAB771777") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

The Part Number displays just fine, however field based on the uniqueID results in a message:

```
DB1A6498-7CC6-4EA0-846A-9B6EAB771777/ is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table .
```

I read through the data table columns to create the grid columns, which display fine, however when attemtping to dynamically create the ItemTemplate, the error occurs.  Putting the brackets "[]" around the uniqueID in the label did not work either.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Did you try double brackets?  If there are actual brackets in the column  name you might need [[DB1A6498-7CC6-4EA0-846A-9B6EAB771777]] - this is often the case in SQL statements.

Comment: Also, if there's a SQL statement behind this, try aliasing that column to another name, Select [DB1A6498-7CC6-4EA0-846A-9B6EAB771777] as GUIDColumn

Comment: There's definitely something related to the brackets.  If I put "x[[DB1A6498-7CC6-4EA0-846A-9B6EAB771777]]]y" for the Eval, the error message doesn't see the first bracket.

If "[[DB1A6498-7CC6-4EA0-846A-9B6EAB771777]]" is entered for Eval, the error message reads:  "[DB1A6498-7CC6-4EA0-846A-9B6EAB771777" which only reflects one of the first two brackets.  No text at the end after the first of the two brackets is recognized.

Time for me to look in to the brackets more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin...your response led me down the path of the brackets.  Based on that, I found information about the DataBinder with the final result being that the Text property of the asp:label reads:

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem,"[DB1A6498-7CC6-4EA0-846A-9B6EAB771777]") %>'
```

This is displaying data from the uniqueID fields with no errors.